# How do I remove links from the left navigation in a flow?

Tags: power-automate, flow

I am automatically creating sharepoint sites on our tenant and have most things done.

However I would like to remove the links (only the links, not the libraries) for Pages and Documents from the left hand navigation.

I cant seem to find a way to do this in my flow. Can anyone help?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That feature is located under site settings>Navigation Elements> Disable Quick Launch on SharePoint.

As far as I know, out-of-box Power Auto option isn't available, but there are PowerShell or PnP option (in conjunction with logic app) and you could configure it to run it automatically when there's a new site created (triggered).

Answer (score 0):

The default power automate does not have such an operation. If you have to use power automate, you can use other back-end languages to encapsulate an api that modifies navigation, whether using the azure function or using c#, python, or java. Then send an HTTP request in power automate, you can achieve your needs.

[Authenticate SharePoint Using Pnp.Framework In An Azure Functions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authenticate-sharepoint-using-pnp-framework-in-an-azure-functions/)

[Update Navigation programmatically for SharePoint Modern sites using SharePoint CSOM](https://asishpadhy.com/2018/06/28/update-navigation-programmatically-for-sharepoint-modern-sites-using-sharepoint-csom/)

And send an HTTP request action needs a premium license.
[image]